# How long has へ been a replacement for に in indicating direction? Is it similar to を in that context?

Tags: particles, history, direction

After reading an answer on this site about some particulars of particle usage, I recently got a copy of *The Structure of the Japanese Language* by Kuno. It has been an interesting read, although the copyright of the book is dated 1973 and the last printing (as far as the copy of the book I have is concerned) is 1980.

In the chapter for "Place Particles" を、に、で, the author doesn't seem to include へ in even a footnote, which is strange considering there were forty something pages dedicated to contrasting　は and が.

The usage of を, according to the book, is to indicate unidirectionality over a major portion or dimension of the noun, and に is to indicate that the goal of the motion is the destination, and they are not entirely interchangeable as far as grammatical correctness is concerned. The above usage of seems similar to を that I've seen elsewhere of へ.

I am curious to know:

1. How similar are を and へ particles in the above context?
2. Is を commonly used nowadays in the above context?
3. How long has へ been in use in the above context? I'm not sure how to find a good source on this, either.

Edit: An example from the book, using the (Nihon-Shiki, I think) spelling present there

```
a. miti o aruku 'to walk along the street'

b. miti ni aruku 'to walk to the street'

c. miti de aruku 'to walk on the street (probably back and forth, and across)'
```

Comment: Do you have some sample sentences from the book? It's hard to tell what context you are talking about only from your explanation.

Comment: I believe the usage of へ for directions has been in place since ancient Japanese, considering the etymology of 前, which used to be 前{まへ}, and actually meant 目方{まへ}, 目指す方向。へ here in ancient Japanese already denoted directionality. Also 行方{ゆくえ}, formerly 行方{ゆくへ}

Comment: @aguijonazo I added an example from the book to illustrate 3 cases.

Comment: I would never say 道に歩く, at least not in the sense of "to the street." 道へ歩く sounds slightly less bad but it's totally different from 道を歩く.

Comment: @aguijonazo my impression was that that for 道に歩く there would be some sort of goal (like maybe a parade or festival), or maybe someone in a car picking you up. Or is the sense of  道 in that sentence more "onto" the street than the "to the edge" of the street? Or is it something else?

Comment: For me 道に歩く is a literary and stilted way of saying 道を歩く or 道で歩く.

Comment: This is related: [Why is 街に歩く not grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44980/43676)

Comment: From my understanding of the linked post, this is more about the usage of 歩く than the destination in this case, and ◯に歩く usually sounds weirder than ◯へ歩く when the latter is permissible, since you wouldn't use 歩く unless the manner of movement was particularly relevant, which is also when へ is preferred over に. Is that accurate?

Comment: 歩く is a verb of action, not of movement like 行く. Unlike “to” in English, に alone is not powerful enough to shift its focus to the destination. You need to rely on other expressions like 〜に向かって or the helper verb 行く (to make it 歩いていく). へ sounds less bad (to me) because it doesn’t pinpoint a destination like に. It’s more like “toward(s)” than “to.” But again, it’s totally different from を. I can’t think of a single context where へ has a similar meaning to を. So I don’t know what exactly you are asking.

Comment: This might help. [この道をまっすぐ行ってください。 Why を and not で?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6869/43676)